# Is there a more elegant way to write this code?

Tags: php

```
<?php if (!empty($box1) && !empty($box2)) { echo ' | content here'; } ?>

<?php if (!empty($box1) && empty($box2)) { echo 'content here'; } ?>
```

Basically, I want to get rid of the pipe if box2 is empty. Is there a better way to write this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if (!empty($box1)) { echo (empty($box2) ? '' : ' | ') . 'content here'; } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. Just a side question. What is that question mark used for next to ($box2)?

Comment: It's the [PHP ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

Comment: It's a ternary operator.  Basically, `(A ? B : C)` runs A, interprets the result as a binary.  If the result is true, then B is evaluated.  Otherwise, C is evaluated.  As an example, `echo ($x == 1 ? 'x=1' : 'x!=1');` will print "x=1" if $x is 1.  if $x is not 1, then "x!=1" will be printed

Comment: Thank you @Steven Xu and @Foo Bah.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's the "best" way to write it elegantly without having a grander scheme of things, but at least you can shorten it as follows:

```
<?php if(!empty($box1)) { echo (!empty($box2) && ' |') . 'content here'; } ?>
```

Alternately, if you don't like the `&&` style, you can use a ternary operator:

```
<?php if(!empty($box1)) { echo (!empty($box2) ? ' |' : '') . 'content here'; } ?>
```

Or another conditional.

Coarsely, if "most" elegant way would be to take a closer look at what `$box1` and `$box2` represent and then create a view helper (in the MVC methodology) along the lines of:

```
class SomeModel {
  int $box1;
  int $box2;
  function make_suffix() {
    $suffix = '';
    if(!empty($this->box1)) {
      if(!empty($this->box2)) {
        $suffix .= ' | ';
      }
      $suffix .= 'content here'; 
    }
    return $suffix;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (!empty(&box1)) {
  if (!empty($box2) {
    echo ' | ';
  }
  echo 'content here';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just [ternary operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a):

```
<?php echo !empty($box1) ? ( !empty($box2) ? ' | ' : '' ) . 'content here' : '' ?>
```